# mongodb crossjoin query to provide sum of one field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is demo data.
Consider I have following documents in mongodb collection called transaction

```
{User:'user1',transaction:10,shop:'shop1'},
{User:'user1',transaction:20,shop:'shop2'},
{User:'user2',transaction:60,shop:'shop3'},
{User:'user3',transaction:80,shop:'shop4'},
{User:'user1',transaction:50,shop:'shop2'},
{User:'user2',transaction:5,shop:'shop1'},
{User:'user3',transaction:11,shop:'shop4'},
{User:'user2',transaction:32,shop:'shop2'},
{User:'user3',transaction:56,shop:'shop1'},
{User:'user1',transaction:89,shop:'shop3'},
{User:'user2',transaction:12,shop:'shop4'}
```

And I need result with all possible combinations and transaction should be summed for them like

```
User1 Shop1 10
User1 Shop2 70
User1 Shop3 89
User1 Shop4 0
User2 Shop1 5
User2 Shop2 32
User2 Shop3 60
User2 Shop4 12
User3 Shop1 56
User3 Shop2 0
User3 Shop3 0
User3 Shop4 91
```

Can you please help me with query of optimal process to achive result.
Thanks in Advance

I am getting User and Shop combination list using follosing query, but not sure how I will get sum for transaction in it.

```
test> db.transaction.aggregate(
[{$lookup: 
{
  from: 'transaction',
  pipeline: [{$project: {_id:0, User:1}}],
  as: 'User'
}}, 
{$unwind: 
{
  path: "$User"
}}, 
{$project: {
User: 1,
shop: 1
}}
])
test>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `group` your data.

**Note:** You don't get `User* Shop* 0`

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        User: "$User",
        shop: "$shop"
      },
      transaction: {
        $sum: "$transaction"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      User: "$_id.User",
      shop: "$_id.shop",
      transaction: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      User: 1,
      shop: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iv-gaeCYZpW)